# Create dataframe of certain XML element's text python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I am trying to create a dataframe out the XML code as shown below

```
<Structure>
    <Field>
        <Field_Name>GAMEREF</Field_Name>
        <Field_Type>Numeric</Field_Type>
        <Field_Len>4</Field_Len>
        <Field_Dec>0</Field_Dec>
    </Field>
    ...
    <Field>
        <Field_Name>WINLOSS</Field_Name>
        <Field_Type>Character</Field_Type>
        <Field_Len>1</Field_Len>
        <Field_Dec>0</Field_Dec>
    </Field>
</Structure>

<Records>
    <Record>
        <GAMEREF>1217</GAMEREF>
        <YEAR>2021</YEAR>
        (MORE ELEMENTS I DO NOT CARE ABOUT)
        <GAMENO>1</GAMENO>
        <WINLOSS>W</WINLOSS>
    </Record>
    ...
    <Record>
        <GAMEREF>1220</GAMEREF>
        <YEAR>2021</YEAR>
        (MORE ELEMENTS I DO NOT CARE ABOUT)
        <GAMENO>4</GAMENO>
        <WINLOSS>L</WINLOSS>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

The structure section of the XML code that is irrelevant to the dataframe I am trying to create.

I am trying to only use the XML elements of GAMEREF, YEAR, GAMENO, and WINLOSS as there are more in the XML for the Record elements.

I have tried using code as shown below to get this to work, but when I run the code I get the error of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xtree = et.parse("gamedata.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()

df_cols = ["GAME REF","YEAR", "GAME NO", "WIN LOSS"]
rows = []

for child in xroot.iter():
     s_gameref = child.find('GAMEREF').text,
     s_year = child.find('YEAR').text,
     s_game_no = child.find('GAMENO').text,
     s_winloss = child.find('WINLOSS').text

     rows.append({"GAME REF": s_gameref,"YEAR": s_year, 
             "GAME NO": s_game_no, "WIN LOSS": s_winloss})

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)
```

The code is based off other stuff I have seen on the Stack and other sites, but nothing is working yet.

Ideal dataframe output is below

| GAME REF | YEAR | GAME NO | WIN LOSS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1217 | 2021 | 1 | W |
| 1218 | 2021 | 2 | W |
| 1219 | 2021 | 3 | L |
| 1220 | 2021 | 4 | L |

Thanks

EDIT - NOT SURE WHAT IS GOING ON WITH MY TABLE, BUT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS
[image: table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below is what you are looking for. (Just loop over the "interesting" sub elements of `Record`). The logic of the code is in the line that starts with `data = [...`. The 2 loops can be found there.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r><Structure>
    <Field>
        <Field_Name>GAMEREF</Field_Name>
        <Field_Type>Numeric</Field_Type>
        <Field_Len>4</Field_Len>
        <Field_Dec>0</Field_Dec>
    </Field>
    ...
    <Field>
        <Field_Name>WINLOSS</Field_Name>
        <Field_Type>Character</Field_Type>
        <Field_Len>1</Field_Len>
        <Field_Dec>0</Field_Dec>
    </Field>
</Structure>

<Records>
    <Record>
        <GAMEREF>1217</GAMEREF>
        <YEAR>2021</YEAR>
        <GAMENO>1</GAMENO>
        <WINLOSS>W</WINLOSS>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <GAMEREF>1220</GAMEREF>
        <YEAR>2021</YEAR>
        <GAMENO>4</GAMENO>
        <WINLOSS>L</WINLOSS>
    </Record>
</Records></r>'''
fields = {'GAMEREF':'GAME REF', 'YEAR':'YEAR', 'GAMENO':'GAME NO','WINLOSS':'WIN LOSS'}
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [{display_name: rec.find(element_name).text for element_name,display_name in fields.items()} for rec in root.findall('.//Record')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
  GAME REF  YEAR GAME NO WIN LOSS
0     1217  2021       1        W
1     1220  2021       4        L
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Is there a way to do this without directly adding the XML to the code? (first time working with XML). The root = et.fromstring(xml) portion is what I think is causing my question since I have been using xtree = et.parse("gamedata.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot().

Comment: Just replace fromstring with parse(filename) and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xtree = et.parse("gamedata.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()

df_cols = ["GAME REF","YEAR", "GAME NO", "WIN LOSS"]
rows = []

for record in xroot:
     s_gameref = record.find('GAMEREF').text
     s_year = record.find('YEAR').text
     s_game_no = record.find('GAMENO').text
     s_winloss = record.find('WINLOSS').text

     rows.append({"GAME REF": s_gameref,"YEAR": s_year,
             "GAME NO": s_game_no, "WIN LOSS": s_winloss})

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)
```

Remove `.iter()`

Comment: I still get the error of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" with that code.